# Funcionamiento de Arrays.sort(Object[ ] a)

Tags: java

Llevo dos (02) días pegándome con este código para averiguar su funcionamiento paso a paso, pero no consigo desvelarlo del todo.

Llamo al método `Arrays.sort(misempleados)` para ordenar los empleados por salario (`misempleados` es un array de la clase `Empleado` en el que en cada posición está almacenado un objeto de la clase Empleado).

Si echo un vistazo a la **API** de **Java** me dice que para ejecutar este método tengo que implementar en la clase `Empleado` la interfaz Comparable y por lo tanto, tengo que sobrescribir su método `compareTo(T o)`.

El programa funciona sin problemas, pero no entiendo el funcionamiento de `compareTo()`. Yo no lo llamo en ningún momento, no utilizo ningún objeto de la clase empleado para llamarlo ¿Podríais explicarme el funcionamiento del método `Arrays.sort(Object[] a)` y cómo y cuándo llama al método `compareTo(T o)` de la clase `Empleado`? También me gustaría saber a qué hace referencia `Object` y qué admitiría como parámetro.

Espero poder ver la luz sobre este método ya que llevo dos (02) días investigando su funcionamiento.

```java
Empleado[] misempleados = new Empleado[6];

misempleados[0] = new Empleado("Diego", 1127.65, 2017, 5, 8);
misempleados[1] = new Empleado("Jesus", 1359.12, 2019, 3, 22);
misempleados[2] = new Empleado("Laura", 1220.90, 2009, 8, 15);
misempleados[3] = new Empleado("Antonio");
misempleados[4] = jefe_RRHH; //Polimorfismo en acción. Principio de sustitución.

misempleados[5] = new Jefatura ("María", 95000, 1999, 5, 26);

Jefatura jefa_finanzas = (Jefatura) misempleados[5];
jefa_finanzas.Establece_Incentivo(55000);

Arrays.sort(misempleados);

for (Empleado e : misempleados) {
  e.Sube_sueldo (5);
  System.out.println("Id: " + e.Dame_Id() + "\n" + "Nombre: " + e.Dame_nombre() + "\n" + "Sueldo: " + e.Dame_sueldo() + "\n" + "Fecha de contratación: " + e.Dame_Fecha_Contrato());
  System.out.println();
}
```

```java
package Empleados;

import java.util.*;

public class Empleado implements Comparable {

  private String nombre;
  private double sueldo;
  private Date alta_contrato;
  private int id;
  private static int idsig = 1;

  // Constructor1
  public Empleado(String nombre, double sueldo, int year, int month, int day) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.sueldo = sueldo;

    GregorianCalendar calendario = new GregorianCalendar(year, month - 1, day);
    alta_contrato = calendario.getTime();

    id = idsig;
    idsig++;
  }

  // Constructor2
  public Empleado(String nombre) {
    this (nombre, 2093.60, 2000, 1, 1);
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  public int compareTo(Object miObjeto) {
    Empleado otroEmpleado = (Empleado) miObjeto;

    if (this.sueldo < otroEmpleado.sueldo) {
      return -1;
    } else if (this.sueldo == otroEmpleado.sueldo) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }
}

// Abajo hay getters y setters de la clase
```

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > ¿Podríais explicarme el funcionamiento del método Arrays.sort(Object[] a) y cómo y cuándo llama al método compareTo(T o) de la clase Empleado?

El método [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])) internamente invoca al método `compareTo` y lo usa como condicional para poder comparar los objetos.

El parámetro `Object[]a` del método `sort` indica que se puede pasar un arreglo de objetos de cualquier tipo, es decir, arreglos que almacenen objetos de tipo `Empleado`, `Jefe`, etc. Si el parámetro fuera de tipo `Empleado[]a`, el método `sort` quedaría limitado, debido a que, solo podrá ordenar objetos de tipo `Empleado`.

Ahora, para entender en que momento el método `sort` invoca el método `compareTo`, plantearé un ejemplo: Imagínate que eres un desarrollador de oracle y te tocó programar el método `sort` (de la clase `Arrays`) usando el algoritmo burbuja. Entonces el código quedaría de esta forma:

```java
class Arrays
{
    public static void sort(Object[] a)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < a.length - 1; j++)
            {
                if(a[j].compareTo(a[j+1]) > 0)
                {
                    Object tmp = a[j+1];
                    a[j+1] = a[j];
                    a[j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Other methods...
}
```

Si compilamos, nos dará el siguiente error:

```java
cannot find symbol
if(a[j].compareTo(a[j+1]) > 0)
symbol: method compareTo
location: class Object
```

Este error de compilación se debe porqué el parámetro `a` del método `sort` es de tipo `Object[]`, esto quiere decir que el compilador asume que todos los objetos del arreglo son de tipo `Object`, sin embargo, la clase `Object` en ningún momento tiene implementado el método `compareTo`, entonces como el compilador no lo encuentra, da ese error.

Si nos fijamos en el código fuente de la clase [Arrays.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/be44bff34df4/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java), hacen una conversión explicita de la siguiente manera:

```java
if(((Comparable)a[j]).compareTo(a[j+1]) > 0)
```

Esto le indica al compilador que cualquier objeto que pertenezca al arreglo implementará el método `compareTo` porqué se asume que su clase implementa la interfaz `Comparable`, sin embargo, se corre el riesgo que si no se llegara a implementar, la `JVM` lanzaría una excepción.

Debo recalcar que esto solo fue únicamente un ejemplo, el método [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])) en realidad lo implementaron con el método de ordenamiento `mergesort`, sin embargo, el funcionamiento es parecido, este método internamente debe usar una condición codificada de esta manera:

```java
if(((Comparable)a[j]).compareTo(a[j+1]) > 0)
```

**Observación:**

No es necesario agregar tantas condiciones en tu método `compareTo`:

```java
  public int compareTo(Object miObjeto) {
    Empleado otroEmpleado = (Empleado) miObjeto;

    if (this.sueldo < otroEmpleado.sueldo) {
      return -1;
    } else if (this.sueldo == otroEmpleado.sueldo) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }
```

Simplemente lo puedes hacer de esta forma:

```java
public int compareTo(Object miObjeto) 
{
    Empleado otroEmpleado = (Empleado) miObjeto;
    return this.sueldo - otroEmpleado.sueldo;
}
```

Y se lo interpreta de esta manera:

Si el sueldo del empleado (objeto1) es mayor al sueldo del empleado2 (objeto2), entonces, el método `compareTo` retorna un entero positivo, en la cual indica que el primer objeto es el mayor y esto puede servir para ordenar objetos de menor a mayor.

Para ordenarlo de forma descendente, cambiamos el orden de la expresión:

```java
this.sueldo - otroEmpleado.sueldo
```

a:

```java
otroEmpleado.sueldo - this.sueldo
```