# Cómo puede Arrays.sort ordenar listas de objetos String

Tags: java

tengo esto:

```
        m_string[0] = "hola";
        m_string[1] = "mundo";
        m_string[2] = "otro";
        Arrays.sort(m_string);
        for (int i = 0; i < m_string.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(m_string[i]);
        }
```

Lo ordena bien, pero el parámetro de Arrays.sort es un Object[], entonces que sabe la implementación de Arrays con Object del tipo String? No entiendo cómo puede hacer la ordenación.

Comment: En Java la [clase `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) extiende de `Object`, como de hecho todas las clases del lenguaje.

Comment: Posible duplicado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/325714/funcionamiento-de-arrays-sortobject-a/325776#325776

Answer (score 0):

En Java la [clase `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) extiende de `Object`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De hecho, [como dice la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), todas las clases del lenguaje extienden de `Object`:

> La clase `Object` es la raíz de la jerarquía de clases. Cada clase
>   tiene `Object` como una superclase. Todos los objetos, incluidas las
>   matrices, implementan los métodos de esta clase.

Aparte de eso, el método [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) recibe en parámetro un array de  `Object` en el cual todos los miembros deben poder implementar la interfaz `Comparable`, como dice la definición del método:

> Ordena la matriz especificada de objetos en orden ascendente, de
>   acuerdo con el orden natural de sus elementos. Todos los elementos en
>   la matriz deben implementar la interfaz `Comparable`. Además, todos
>   los elementos de la matriz deben ser mutuamente comparables (es decir,
>   e1.compareTo (e2) no debe arrojar una ClassCastException para ningún
>   elemento e1 y e2 en la matriz).

Ese requisito lo cumple también  `String`, como se puede ver en la imagen más arriba.